# How to install pyyaml into `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`

Tags: python, python-3.x, ros, pyyaml

I'm trying to rosrun my python file, but got

```
$ rosrun forklift seg.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rvl224/brian2lee/gazebo/forklift_test/src/ros1_wiki/forklift/script/seg.py", line 3, in <module>
    import rospy 
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from std_msgs.msg import Header
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/std_msgs/msg/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._Bool import *
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/std_msgs/msg/_Bool.py", line 6, in <module>
    import genpy
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/genpy/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . message import Message, SerializationError, DeserializationError, MessageException, struct_I
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/genpy/message.py", line 48, in <module>
    import yaml
ImportError: No module named yaml
```

I already installed pyyaml in  `/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3` and `./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`. But it seems to look for pyyaml in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`. How do I install it into `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`?

EDIT: I think I've installed it by `pip install --target /opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages pyyaml`, but rosrun-ing the seg.py got different error. I don't know if it's still a pyyaml problem now.

```
$ rosrun forklift seg.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rvl224/brian2lee/gazebo/forklift_test/src/ros1_wiki/forklift/script/seg.py", line 3, in <module>
    import rospy 
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from std_msgs.msg import Header
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/std_msgs/msg/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._Bool import *
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/std_msgs/msg/_Bool.py", line 6, in <module>
    import genpy
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/genpy/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . message import Message, SerializationError, DeserializationError, MessageException, struct_I
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/genpy/message.py", line 48, in <module>
    import yaml
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 362
    class YAMLObject(metaclass=YAMLObjectMetaclass):
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You appear to have your distributions in two different places: */opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3* and */usr/lib/python3*, and the `rospy` system appears not to be looking in the second location.  Are you working in a virtual environment for this?

Comment: Update  `py -m  pip install PyYAML --upgrade`  The version was PyYAML 6.0.1

Comment: @OldBoy I'm not in virtual env

Comment: @toyotaSupra `py -m  pip install PyYAML --upgrade` doesn't work `/usr/bin/py:16: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.10 it will stop working
` appear the problem is on py. So I tried without py `pip install PyYAML --upgrade`, though some errors appear it installed successfully. However the errors on rosrun remains the same.

Comment: @brian2lee As I said you seem to have two distributions installed, so i can only assume that you need to install `yaml` into the */opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3* tree.

Comment: @OldBoy How do I install it into a specific location?

Comment: @brian2lee I am not sure, but you first need to work out why you have two different installations in the first place.

Comment: As a workaround, you can try copying some YAML-related files and directories from `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` to `/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages`. However, for the proper answer you may want to ask on https://answers.ros.org/ .

Comment: @pts Ros Q&A is read only now, it has been transition to Robotics Stack Exchange. I  really dont understand the difference between stackoverflow and robotic since they share the same account so I just choose one to ask.

Comment: @pts Straight copy paste a package doesn't look like an good idea. There's a high chance it'll ruin the whole system.

Comment: @brian2lee: Fortunately the copy is easy and quick to try and undo.

Comment: And there's another pyyaml in my python 3.8, `pip3 install pyyaml` got
`Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (6.0.1)`. My ubuntu is a mess

Comment: @pts I don't think c&p is an option now. There're tons of `yaml` or `pyyaml` related thingy scattered around my `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`. Who knows which to copy from